# Covering spaces and Automorphisms

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

I need to find for the groups $G$ a connected degree-4 cover $\hat{B}\rightarrow B$ such that Aut($\hat{B}\rightarrow B$) is isomorphic to $G$

1. $G \cong 1$
2. $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}$
3. $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$
4. $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{4}$

I am trying to use automorphisms of graphs and looking where do the vertices get send and I know that all of these can be realized if I take for B the graph with one vertex and two edges.

Thanks